# convert degrees decimal minutes to decimal degrees

Tags: php, gps

How can convert `degrees decimal minutes` to `decimal degrees`
on **NMEA 0183** standard GPS trackers send position as degrees decimal minutes and need to convert.

**Inputs :**

```
5546.263 /*(mean = 55° 46.263'N)*/
3739.712 /*(mean = 37° 39.712'E)*/
```

**Outputs :**

```
55.771050
37.661867
```

Some inputs have a zero at first , like as above (`3739.712` came from GPS device like `03739.712`)

I try to it my self but have problem on first step :)
first problem is how `degrees decimal minutes` can convert to `decimal degrees`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know PHP, but if you can split the (string?) "5546.263" into 55 and 46.263 (degrees and decimal minutes), you can convert to decimal degrees with `55 + (46.263 / 60)`.

In other words, it is `degrees + (minutes / 60)`.

Comment: Thanks David , this is formula all I need :) (I'll accept it on 3 minutes)